# convert a nested string into JSON object javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a nested query String like

```
var str = "( ( Sentence starts with any of null AND Sentence starts with any of null ) AND Sentence starts with any of null )"
```

How do I convert it by splitting from AND operator into a JSON object using javascript which should look like:

```
{  
   "group":{  
      "operator":"AND",
      "rules":[  
         {  
            "group":{  
               "operator":"AND",
               "rules":[  
                  object1‌​,
                  object2
               ]
            }
         },
         object3
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: That's neither a valid JavaScript nor a valid JSON object. Did you mean to put some quotes in?

Comment: Also, please verify: it seems you want the split to happen on inner `()` as well as `AND` statements. Is that correct?

Comment: yes @MatthewHerbst that's correct, I want to split it by inner () as well as AND

Comment: Can you please make your output a valid JavaScript or JSON object based on the input string so I can modify my answer? It's not clear exactly what goes where.

Comment: Expected output: "{"group":{"operator":"AND","rules":[{"group":{"operator":"AND","rules":[object1, object2]}}, object3]}}" @MatthewHerbst

Comment: @Nikita Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service.  Please try and provide code demonstrating what you've tried so far or at least describe what you've tried.  You can then ask question(s) specific to the issues (if any) that you're facing.

Comment: I have tried splitting the string by getting the inner () and then splitting it by AND. Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avm36z29/1/

Answer (score 1):

In the general sense until your answer is cleaned up:

```
var string = "my cool string AND I love JS AND isn't this cool?";

var operations = string.split(' AND '); // Gives an array: ["my cool string", "I love JS", "isn't this cool?"]

var group = {};

for(var i = 0; i < operations.length; ++i) {
  operations['operator' + i] = operations[i];
}

console.log(group); // { operator1: "my cool string", operator2: "I love JS", operator3: "isn't this cool?"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(group)); // gives JSON string representation of group
```